# Why would a minified js spit out errors after moving to linux server?

Tags: javascript, linux, apache, minify

We have a bunch of captivate elearning files that we play on our web server.  They are just html5 directories - nothing fancy or tech needy I thought.

These all played fine on our old server - windows 2012 r2 apache/php stack.  Never had an issue.

Moved over to a new linux server with apache/php stack and they are having issues loading.

We get Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier for CPM.js.

It is a really large minified js file.  If I unminify it (http://jsbeautifier.org/) it works fine - no errors.

How do I start troubleshooting this?  What would keep a server from reading a minified js file (json mime is on)?

I get the error on line 1

```
if(!window.cp)window.cp = function(str){return document.getElementById(str)};cp.CPProjInit = function(){if(cp && cp.model && cp.model.data) return; cp.model = {}; cp.poolResources = {}; cp.D = cp.model.data = {pref:{acc:1,rkt:0,hsr:1},StAd0:{from:16,to:419,src:'ar/12760.mp3',du:13479},Highlight_Box_1:{type:14,from:358,to:459,rp:0,rpa:0,mdi:'Highlight_Box_1c',retainState:false,immo:false,apsn:'Slide5818',trin:15,trout:15,stl:[{stn:'Normal',stt:0,stsi:[7652]}],stis:0,bstiid:-1,sipst:0,sicbs:false,sihhs:false,sihds:false},Highlight_Box_1c:{b:[912,409,1034,433],uid:7652,sr:cp.fd,dn:'Highlight_Box_1',visible:1,effectiveVi:1,JSONEffectData:false,fc:'#333333',sc:'#ffa100',sw:2,fo:0,foa:0,vbwr:[910,407,1035,434],vb:[910,407,1035,434]},MC$1:{type:15728652,from:444,to:459,rp:0,mdi:'MC$1c'},MC$1c:{b:[985,418,991,424],sr:cp.mcd,dn:'MC$1',visible:1,data:{c:'#0000ff',r:3}},Mouse_1:{type:12,from:1,to:460,rp:0,rpa:0,mdi:'Mouse_1c',retainState:false,immo:false,apsn:'Slide5818',mp:'mouse',afrom:415,ato:459,mpa:{b:[-1,-1,988,421],t:1,s:0},trin:0,trout:0},Mouse_1c:{b:[-1,-1,31,31],uid:5831,sr:cp.fd,ip:'dr/5830.png',dn:'Mouse_1',visible:1,effectiveVi:1,JSONEffectData:false,vbwr:[-1,-1,1020,453],vb:[-1,-1,1020,453]},s2_orange_box:
```

Comment: I think this cannot be solved without more code shown. Some minifier/ugglyfier might introduce syntax errors in complex scripts with maybe unusual characters, I don't know, but there is a chance such tools make mistakes. Check the encoding and try different packers.

Comment: Something else of note is that linux is case sensitive. I don't know if windows is.

Comment: In Chrome you can press F12, in the sources tab on the right side you can pause on exceptions. In the console it shows the error (you can click on it). Chrome dev tools has a beautify button in the left bottom corner that looks like `{}`. Could you please post some of the code that causes the syntax error?

Comment: @HMR not sure that is what you want but copied the code.  Error is on line one.  I am a server/app guy and not good with js so sorry if I am not doing something right.  This is a weird issue because most of our captivates are fine and the rest I have to go through one by one and deminify.

Comment: The Chrome console can show you the exact error in the JS debugger, not only the line.